# Why won't videos on some websites play?

Tags: firefox, video, flash, codecs, video-streaming

I recently installed ubuntu on my laptop and was able to install the flash plugin.

I am able to play youtube videos on firefox with no problem. However videos on some websites don't appear, only shows a black box. An example would be tvgolo.com.

I was wondering if there is any fix to this? Maybe I'm missing codecs?

Thanks,
Nazir

Comment: Try libhal, as described here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/10/fixing-amazon-prime-streaming-drm-protected-flash-13-10?utm_source=feedly

Comment: Thanks for the reply but 4od seems to be working fine for me, and I don't think libhal is available anymore. But the tvgolo.com website is still giving me problems.

Comment: See my answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/556320/firefox-34-black-screen-playing-adobe-flash-videos#

Comment: Thanks but I'm now using chromium as my go-to browser so I don't have to worry about that problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I use chrome and `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`. Your site works with that.

If you are not willing to change browsers, make sure you have `flashplugin-installer` installed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I'm aware that it works with chrome, but I've been using firefox for a long time now and I don't want to change to chrome. I do have flashplugin-installer installed and still doesn't work.